# Rails 3.1 Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to route a particular object's show method to the root path of my app, but I'm having trouble routing it anywhere at all for that matter. So I guess this break down into two questions:

1. If I wanted /pages/2 for example to go to the root path, how would I do this?
2. Also, if I wanted to make the url take a name or some attribute (eg. /username would find_by_username and show the correct page) how would I do this?

I've looked at a couple railscasts and the rails guide on routing, but I seem to be missing something...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I should warn you. Because you want to break down REST pattern. REST was well designed by clever folks and if you want to redefine some of it's functionality - so you have some incorrect logic in your App design.

Now to answer your question:
1. You can try something like this:

```
match "pages/:id", redirect {|params| "your_root_url" if params[:id] == 2}
```

2. Look at [to_param documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) for more detail.

I hope i helped you alittle